# How can I specify values for Post[] in a Prisma schema with a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: postgresql

I'm having this problem with database logic
I have a Postgresql database with two schema **User** and **Post** like below

This is code to create a user

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    id: "",
    name: "uchiha",
    email: "itachi",
    createdAt: "2005-05-05",
    updatedAt: "" ,
    posts: Post[0],
  }
})
```

This is prisma schema to generate **User** table

```
// schema.prisma

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["jsonProtocol"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
}

model Post {
  id        String     @default(cuid()) @id
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false)
  author    User?   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String?
}

model User {
  id            String       @default(cuid()) @id
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
  posts         Post[]
  @@map(name: "users")
}
```

This is a one to many relationship, a **User** have many **Posts**. I want to specify the values of "post" in **User** which type is Post[]. I want to add Post[0], Post[1], Post[2] values to "post". Tried different ways but all causing errors. Really appreciate if anyone could help. Thank you